# After uninstalling yaru theme ubuntu 22.04 is not working in dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, yaru

This is response getting in terminal:

```
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD NSS Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for AutoFS Service responder socket. [DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD PAC Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD PAM Service responder private socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD PAM Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD SSH Service responder socket. [DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD Sudo Service responder socket.
Starting Accounts Service...
[OK] Started Regular background program processing daemon.
Starting Switcheroo Control Proxy service...
Starting User Login Management...
Starting Thermal Daemon Service...
Starting Disk Manager...
Starting HPA supplicant...
Starting Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled...
OK ] Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
OK ] Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
[
[
[ OK ] Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
[ OK ] Started System Logging Service.
[ OK ] Finished Remove Stale Online ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots. [ OK 1 Finished Secure Boot updates for DB and DBX.
[ OK 1 Finished Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
[FAILED] Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
```